# Login Feature Storing Username/Password

Tags: php, mysql, object, shared

I am using ActionScript 3 in Flash. I have mysql Login database. I would like to provide the typical "Remember me" checkbox, that the user can tick when logging in as a simple user, so he doesn't have to type in username and password every time.
My php is somewhat limited So I was considering using the shared object flush method to store data on a user browsers is the a feasible and secure approach? Or, would you recommend for security reasons going the traditional route place a function in a php file to check for cookie or a session to see if a user wants to be remembered or not?

Comment: Without code its unable to help you..So try posting your code

Comment: Thanks Deepu for your reply. I just wanted to know which alternative method was the best. This is part of my code from my Flash file. I don't know if this is secure way. var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("loginData"); // to call the shared object. 
if(mySo.data.userName){
// do an auto login
}


// when a user registers, save their data.  
function registerUserF(e:MouseEvent):void{
mySO.data.userName = userName.text;
mySo.data.password = password.text; 
mySo.flush();
}